# In Python, how to count the number '1's in a list of email addresses?

Tags: python, list, count, sublist

Here's what I have so far:

```
emails = ['james1@example.com', 'januline12@januline.com', 'fillip.morris@pm.com',
          'ray@bradbury.org', 'me+you@hotmail.com', 'seven11@gmail.com',
          'noreply@msd.com', 'cars4u@tesla.com']

def email_security_scan(a, b):
    numbers = []
    for item in a:
        for subitem in item.split():
            if subitem == b:
                numbers.append +=1
    print(numbers)

email_security_scan(emails, 1)
```

It doesn't work, returns `[]`.

Comment: Should 1 in 12 need to be considered? Please give the expected output.

Comment: Note that `item.split()` doesn't split anything.

Answer (score 2):

There are some problems with your logic:

- You are using `str.split` on strings with no whitespace. There's no need to split your string.
- You are comparing integers with strings. This won't work.
- You are appending to a list instead of incrementing a counter variable.

So this would work if you need to count the *number of email addresses* containing `'1'`:

```
def email_security_scan(a, b):
    count = 0
    for item in a:
        if str(b) in item:
            count += 1
    print(count)

email_security_scan(emails, 1)

# 3
```

More simply, you can use `sum` with a generator expression:

```
def email_security_scan(a, b):
   print(sum(str(b) in item for item in a))

email_security_scan(emails, 1)

# 3
```

Or to count the *total number of '1's* across all email addresses, you can use `str.join` and then `str.count`:

```
def email_security_scan(a, b):
    print(''.join(a).count(str(b)))

email_security_scan(emails, 1)

# 4
```

Answer (score 1):

The below code will count the number of 1's in each of the items in the list and give the result.

```
emails = ['james1@example.com', 'januline12@januline.com', 'fillip.morris@pm.com',
          'ray@bradbury.org', 'me+you@hotmail.com', 'seven11@gmail.com',
          'noreply@msd.com', 'cars4u@tesla.com']

def email_security_scan(a, b):
    numbers = 0
    for item in a:
        numbers += item.count(b)
     print(numbers)

email_security_scan(emails, '1')
```

For the above example, the output will be 4.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way using `sum()` on generator:

```
emails = [ 'james1@example.com', 'januline12@januline.com', 'fillip.morris@pm.com',
           'ray@bradbury.org', 'me+you@hotmail.com', 'seven11@gmail.com', 
           'noreply@msd.com', 'cars4u@tesla.com' ]

print(sum(1 for email in emails if '1' in email))
# 3
```

Or:

```
print(sum('1' in email for email in emails))
# 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can represent it like so:

```
def checker(x):
    if "1" in x:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

Now getting a count can be as easy as:

```
emails = [checker(x) for x in emails]
sum(emails)
```

What's going on here?

1. `checker` looks for *one or more "1"* in an entry of your list.
2. `emails = [checker(x) for x in emails]` applies `checker` to each
   entry of your list and overwrites the `emails` variable with our new list comprehension.
3. `sum` does just what you would expect.

Answer (score 0):

```
emails = [ 'james1@example.com', 'januline12@januline.com', 'fillip.morris@pm.com',
       'ray@bradbury.org', 'me+you@hotmail.com', 'seven11@gmail.com', 
       'noreply@msd.com', 'cars4u@tesla.com' ]
sum([i.count('1') for i in emails])
```

Output : `4`